# Return Row Data from Spreadsheet having specified string without looping through all Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a task at hand wherein I **need to return the entire Row Data containing a user-defined string**.

One way of achieving it is **looping through all the rows**, but this **works only when you know in which column to search**, as shown using the code given below.

```
var sheetData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
var searchString = "testSearch";

for(var i=0;i<sheetData.getLastRow();i++)
{
  //assuming we know that the search string is going to be in Column 2
  if(sheetData[i][1].search(searchString)!=-1)
  {
    var rowData = sheetData[i];
    return rowData;
  }
}
```

So my question is, is there **any way in which we can achieve** this, **without having to loop through all rows one by one**?

To make the problem statement more clear, I wish to achieve something like the **'Find' feature** as demonstrated in the image below:

[image]

***This would make it very easy to skim through huge data spread across multiple sheets/spreadsheets***.

**Note**: I am searching for a solution to this using **Google Apps Script**.

Comment: Have you try to use the [Array.indexOf()method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) ?

Comment: How do you know that the find feature is not using loops to search for your search string in every cell in the data range?  I would guess that it is.

Comment: Do the columns have a Header/Title row and you know the header where the text will be? If yes, look at the [Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) tutorial and the getRowsData() function in the code.  Then you can loop through and test the cell value for a specific column by the header as opposed to having to know the column number.  Regardless, in a script you will need to loop through the data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that gets the data from the row with the match.  It can be a partial match.  You do not need to know the number of columns or rows.  You do not need to know which column to look in.

To make this code work, replace `Put Sheet Tab Name Here` with the name of the sheet tab to use.  The `searchString` can be passed into the function.  If nothing is passed in, then the code uses a hard coded value for the search.

```
function findRowOfSearchString(searchString) {
  var arrIndexOfAllMatches,dataAsStringWithBrackets,dataRange,i,
      isThereA_Match,j,ll,L,L2,matchOfAllInnerBrackets,numberOfColumns,numberOfRows,
      rowCutOff,rowsOfMatchedData,sh,sheetData,ss,thisIndex,thisMatchIndex,thisRow,thisRowData;

  ll = function(a,b) {
    Logger.log(a + ": " + b)
  }

  if (!searchString) {
    searchString = "testSe";
  }

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sh = ss.getSheetByName('Put Sheet Tab Name Here');//

  dataRange = sh.getDataRange();

  numberOfColumns = dataRange.getNumColumns();
  numberOfRows = dataRange.getNumRows(); //changed 'getNumColumns' to 'getNumRows'

  sheetData = dataRange.getValues();//Get a 2D array of all sheet data

  dataAsStringWithBrackets = JSON.stringify(sheetData);
  //ll('dataAsStringWithBrackets: ',dataAsStringWithBrackets)

  isThereA_Match = dataAsStringWithBrackets.indexOf(searchString);
  //ll('isThereA_Match: ',isThereA_Match)

  if (isThereA_Match === -1) {return;}//There is no match - stop

  arrIndexOfAllMatches = [];

  L = dataAsStringWithBrackets.length;
  //ll('L',L)

  thisMatchIndex = 0;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    //ll('i',i)
    thisMatchIndex = dataAsStringWithBrackets.indexOf(searchString,thisMatchIndex + 1);

    //ll('thisMatchIndex',thisMatchIndex)

    if (thisMatchIndex === -1) {//No more matches were found
      //ll('No more matches found',thisMatchIndex)
      break;
    }

    arrIndexOfAllMatches.push(thisMatchIndex);
  }

  //ll('arrIndexOfAllMatches',arrIndexOfAllMatches)

  matchOfAllInnerBrackets = [];

  thisMatchIndex = 0;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++){
    thisMatchIndex = dataAsStringWithBrackets.indexOf("],[",thisMatchIndex + 1);

    //ll('thisMatchIndex',thisMatchIndex)

    if (thisMatchIndex === -1) {//No more matches were found
      //ll('No more matches found',thisMatchIndex)
      break;
    }

    matchOfAllInnerBrackets.push(thisMatchIndex);
  }

  ll('matchOfAllInnerBrackets',matchOfAllInnerBrackets)

  rowsOfMatchedData = [];
  L = arrIndexOfAllMatches.length;
  L2 = matchOfAllInnerBrackets.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++){
    thisIndex = arrIndexOfAllMatches[i];
    ll('thisIndex: ' ,thisIndex)

    for (j=0;j<L2;j++){
      rowCutOff = matchOfAllInnerBrackets[j];
      ll('rowCutOff: ',rowCutOff)

      if (rowCutOff > thisIndex) {
        ll('greater than: ' ,thisIndex > rowCutOff)
        thisRow = j+1;
        ll('thisRow: ', (thisRow))
        rowsOfMatchedData.push(thisRow)
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  ll('rowsOfMatchedData: ',rowsOfMatchedData)

  L = rowsOfMatchedData.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++){
    thisRowData = sh.getRange(rowsOfMatchedData[i], 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues();
    ll('thisRowData: ',thisRowData)
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sandy...by looking at the logic it seems good, but when i tried to run the code, the following error was displayed : **The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 27, file "Code")**. I suppose that as the variable **dataAs1D_Array** is an Array, the method **indexOf()** is not able to find a match as it is to be used for variables of type **string** only. I referred the article mentioned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

Comment: If there is no match found, then the return value of `indexOf()` is -1 and -1 is not a valid row number for a `getRange()` parameter.  That is why you got the error.  `indexOf()` *can* be used on an array.  I have updated the code in my answer and added a conditional test for whether the returned index number is -1.

Comment: @Sandy...your code works fine when the search string exactly matches an element of the array `dataAs1D_Array` . Although, it does not work when the search string is a sub string of any of the elements which is what will make it exactly like the **find** feature.

Comment: @Sandy...just realized...there will be discrepancy on using the code you shared in case any of the cell contains a **comma** ,i.e **10,000,000**. Here total number of elements in the array **dataAs1D_Array** will be 2 more than the total number of cells, assuming that this is the only cell having such a string.

Comment: I have reworked the code and provided a completely new answer.  It can match a partial string, and does not have a problem with commas.